# Missing rooms issue with generatedMasterView and room material replacement using three.js

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

**1st question: Missing room models**

I used the model-derivative api from Forge with generatedMasterViews params to extract room nodes from the cloud Revit model (BIM360Team) it work perfectly fine for some model but I had the missing room issues with others.

[Successful translated model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2gem.jpg)

Some of the translated model's room nodes was missing and that's weird because their height and phase are the same and the rooms in 2d view were shown.

[2D views has no problem at all](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ptoe5.jpg)

[3D room nodes in the same floor were missing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDNjU.jpg)

So my question is, are their some limitation to extract the room geometry and convert to .svf files? e.g. publish view setting / view range / crop views / crop region ? or something I'm missing in my request ? I tried to align all the parameter or remove some component (e.g. furniture) but the result still the same. If you guys had noticed this issues before please help, your help would be appreciate.

**2nd question: Room mesh and materials**

I've write the function to highlight the selected elements and its work with almost every nodes except the room elements.

```
const highLightElement = (dbId, hexColor) => {
        const myMaterial = createMaterial(hexColor)

        const instanceTree = viewerApp.model.getInstanceTree()
        const fragList = viewerApp.model.getFragmentList()

        instanceTree.enumNodeFragments(dbId, function(fragId) {
            fragList.setMaterial(fragId, myMaterial)
            const fragProxy = viewerApp.impl.getFragmentProxy(viewerApp.model, fragId)
            fragProxy.scale = new window.THREE.Vector3(scaleRatio, scaleRatio, scaleRatio)
            fragProxy.updateAnimTransform()
        }, true)

        viewerApp.impl.invalidate(true)
    }
```

The material of the room was gloomy white but if use section tool on it the section color already change to the color I choose (0xAB00EE - magenta). I don't know that is the room mesh different from others? or might be need some special procedure to do so?

[Successful coloring nodes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbDul.jpg)

[Room nodes coloring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQ9nY.jpg)

[Z-section of colored room nodes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdTSd.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Regarding issue #1, it's possible that there are certain limitations preventing the Forge Model Derivative service from extracting room information but that would be more on the Revit side. If you wouldn't mind sharing the Revit model with us (confidentially) via `forge (dot) help (at) autodesk (dot) com`, we'd be happy to investigate it with the engineering team. In that case, please indicate which rooms are missing, too.

Regarding issue #2, from the Forge Viewer standpoint, rooms are just another geometry in the scene, with the only difference that this geometry is usually transparent and hidden by default. As far as I know, the visibility flag should not interfere with something like setting the material of a fragment but double-check if that really isn't the root cause.